# How to use patch-package to patch TSX files

Tags: typescript, react-native, patch, react-native-tab-view, patch-package

**Problem**

I'm trying to use patch-package to patch a react-native package `react-native-tab-view`, however when I edit the TSX files included in the node_module for react-native-tab-view and apply my patch, the changes are not reflected in my app.

**Structure of node_modules/react-native-tab-view**

Below is a screenshot of the package structure.
[Package Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkXuW.png)

They also uses `@react-native-community/bob` to build the package prior to publishing so it generates a lib folder with a module folder and commonjs folder containing JS files.

**My current stats**

My patch is being created, however the files in /lib/module don't change and the changes are also not reflected in my app when running on the simulator

I'm trying to apply a patch using patch-package after editing the TSX files in /src as opposed to the JS files in module /lib/module as it is much simpler to implement.

**Environment**
react-native 0.63.0
patch-package 6.2.0
react-native-tab-view 2.15.1
react-native-gesture-handler 1.5.6
react-native-reanimated 1.7.0

**Question**
Am I missing a build or compile step to get react-native-tab-view to generate new JS files from the TSX files I created my patch for?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when a npm package is published it published also with a transpiled version, therefore you should modify the transpiled version with patch-package.

In the case of `react-native-tab-view`, the transpiled version is located in `lib` folder.

You can verify that by checking the lib's `package.json`,

```
  "main": "lib/commonjs/index.js",
  "react-native": "lib/module/index.js",
  "module": "lib/module/index.js",
```

#### Update

My trick is to clone the original repo locally, install it's deps, modify what ever you want in the source (`src`), then build it, and copy the build result over the node_modules in your package, then apply the `patch-package`.

Comment: Thanks @felixmosh !  I see the transpiled source code in lib, but I was hoping to edit the .tsx files since they are also included in the code published by `react-native-tab-view` to npm.  Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: You can modify them, but your app won't consume it, because they go to the package.json files